# Ionic ngFor video playing

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I trying to start the video from ts in the ionic component, but if I call video.play() the video is re-created, I think.

My html code

```
                        <video
                            poster="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545486332-9e0999c535b2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YmxhY2t8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
                            [class.blur]="asset.isHide && !asset.isSave" [attr.id]="'fullscreen-video' + i" #video
                            (click)="playPause(video)">
                            <source [src]="asset.url" type="video/mp4">
                            Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos,
                            but don't worry, you can download it
                            and watch it with your favorite video player!
                        </video>
```

My ts code

```
public playPause(video: HTMLVideoElement): void {
    if (video.paused === true) {
        video.play();
        this.isPlay = true;
    } else {
        this.isPlay = false;
    }
}
```

error that was detected only in debug mode: executeListenerWithErrorHandling

after that error the video element in html is re-created

Comment: It reproduce only in ngFor 
If I create video without ngFor all works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix but I use data from `@Input` for `ngFor` loop and because of this there was a problem

I fix it by rewriting `@Input` variable in another variable and use new in `ngFor`

Answer (score 0):

you should get video Element by Id:.

html:

```
<video
    poster="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545486332-9e0999c535b2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YmxhY2t8ZW58MHx8MHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
    [class.blur]="asset.isHide && !asset.isSave" [attr.id]="'fullscreen-video' + i" #video (click)="playPause($event, 'fullscreen-video' + i)" controls="false">
    <source [src]="asset.url" type="video/mp4">
    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos,
    but don't worry, you can download it
    and watch it with your favorite video player!
</video>
```

.ts:

```
playPause($event, id) {
    let myVideo: any = document.getElementById(id);
    if (myVideo.paused) {
        myVideo.play();
    }
    else {
        myVideo.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `#myvideo` and [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-html5-video-player-hkgu8w